# Java Framework for creating Ajax Websites (as opposed to web applications)

Tags: java, ajax, frameworks, web

I'm looking for a java framework to develop a website that will contain various AJAXy style components on it, but will use tradition page refreshes when switching between pages. I understand that there are a lot of java based frameworks for building web applications (GWT, ZK etc.) but from what I can see these are good for building swing style web applications rather than traditional websites with Ajax components.

So my question is what java frameworks would you suggest using for this case?

Comment: The framework I know best, Apache Wicket, is a framework for "building swing style web applications" with "traditional page refreshes when switching between pages" but provides "various AJAX style components". The same is true - as far as I know - for GWT.

Comment: I've used wicket, which is generally nice to work with. The only issue I have is that new components are created and stored on the server, requiring a server request to get the html/javascript for that component. I guess I could use JQuery components to get around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost any (good) JS component library will allow you to insert the library components (UI widgets) into your multi page application.
Typically, your page loads and on load, you instantiate the (AJAX enabled) UI components and insert them into the page's DOM (usually bind them to some placeholder div tags on the page)

With the above concept out of our way, you want to look for a library or combination of libraries working together that
-Have the UI widgets you are looking for.
-Integrates (fairly easily) with Java.

Following possible options come to my mind

1. RichFaces with JSF as mentioned by the above poster.
2. [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui) and [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) combination
3. [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/) + [directjngine](http://code.google.com/p/directjngine/)

I am sure there are a lot more options but ones listed above are the ones that I have used successfully on production projects.